# Can *narrow minded* be positive?

Tags: meaning, etymology, meaning-in-context

As narrow is being not wide and not flexible, can it also be upright?

Comment: What do the dictionaries say?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it meantions not wide and not flexible but it is neutral. I know *narrow minded* can be negative as "not open minded", I'm asking if it can be something like "uncorruptible" synonym.

Comment: I've never come across a use of "narrow minded" that _was_ positive: your construction would be possible, but so unusual it would need a lot of contextual support (ie, it isn't a natural reading in isolation).

Comment: Yep, it would be unwise to attempt to use "narrow minded" in a positive sense, except perhaps in a jocular way with appropriate context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dominant usage of the phrase has negative connotations; you would have great difficulty convincing someone that it was a compliment. If you want "upright", you might be looking to integrate *the straight and narrow*.

Comment: Nice illustration of the idiosyncrasies that make the language so problematic. I mean fun. If _fun_'s been sufficiently adjectived yet.

Comment: I don't know how to use `the straight and the narrow`, should it only be with `not leaving` or `keeping to`?

Comment: "That guy really knows how to walk the strait and narrow." Note that the phrase properly uses *strait* (not *straight*), meaning tight, with no room to maneuver.

Answer (score 5):

Use ***focused*** for a positive touch, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I'm focused, you're rigid, he's narrow-minded. Somebody-I-can't-remember's third-person-singular view of reality.

Comment: It was one of the *good* part I was thinking about also. But I wanted to use *narrow*